# Finite dimension implies A[a]=A(a)

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I was trying to prove following statement:

Let $A \subseteq F$ be field extension and $a \in F$. Then $A[a] = \{f(a)\,|\,f \in A[x]\}$. Prove that if $A[a]$ is finite dimensional as vector space over A, then $A[a]=A(a)$

All my attempts were unsuccessful, how do we prove such thing?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How do we prove it — sorry, I was editing at the same time as you were writing this message.

Comment: Let A[a] is of finite dimension and the dimension be $d$. Consider $\{1, a, a^2, \cdots, a^d\}$ which is linearly dependent over $A$. This implies $a^{d} = \sum_{j=0}^{d-1}a_ja^j$ where $a_j \in A$ some elements. Now consier the power series of inverses of nonzero element in $A[a]$, which should be the $A[a]$ by above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT.** Use the fact that $A[a]$ is finite dimensional as a vector space over $A$ to show that there is a polynomial for which $a$ is a root, say of degree $n$. There is then a minimal polynomial for $a$. [If you have not learned this, [read the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(field_theory)#:~:text=In%20field%20theory%2C%20a%20branch,a%20root%20of%20the%20polynomial.) and prove that such a polynomial exists using division and your polynomial for which $a$ vanishes.] Then show any higher powers ($\geq n$) of $a$ can be expressed in terms of lower powers of $a$ using this irreducible minimal polynomial. Explain then how you can perform addition/subtraction using these lower powers of $a$. Then you have shown (you may have to verify a few things) that $A[a]$ is a field. Then you just need to see/explain how this shows $A[a]=A(a)$.

Comment: I see your point, but I don’t get how it shows that $A[a] = A(a)$?

Comment: @behaxa Another hint then: $A(a)$ is the *smallest* field containing $a$ and $A$. You  should be able to justify from there. If you struggle, you can prove (fairly easily using isomorphism theorems) that $A[a] \cong A[x]/m(x)$, where $m(x)$ is the minimal polynomial. Then Define $A[x] \to A(a)$ via $p(x) \to p(a)$. Explain why this is a homomorphism with $(m(x))$ in the kernel.This induces a homomorphism $A[x]/m(x) \to A(a)$. But $A[x]/m(x)$ is a field (why) and the map is not the zero map (why). Because maps between fields are either injective or $0$, the map is an isomorphism with its image.

Comment: But the image is then a subfield of $A(a)$, containing $A$ and $a$, so that by the definition of $A(a)$.....

Comment: Ok I think i got it, thank you very much!